# Why does the following logical operator 'not' statement evaluate to true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

```
print(not 42 == "any_string")
```

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44FeS.png)

`not 42` evaluates to False and "any_string" would evaluate to a boolean True.
So, `not 42 == "Answer"` should evaluate to False but it evaluates to True. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

it's order of preference

first this condition will be executed `42 == "any string"`  and the output of this is `False`

then comes `not` so  `not False` is `True`

this is why the output is `True`

Answer (score 0):

The true order is:
First: `42 == "any_string"` --> false
Second: `not false` --> true
So,the input is true

`42 == "any_string"` is  a conditional statement.
So,`not 42 == "any_string"` will judge the `42 == "any_string"`firstly,
just like `if 42 == "any_string"`.